# Serializing and Deserializing uint64_t - different results on different platforms

Tags: c++, c, serialization

I serialize and deserialize the uint64_t with two helper functions in my code:

```
void CSerializer::Write_uint64(const uint64_t& ruiValue )
{

#if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 56));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 48));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 40));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 32));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 24));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 16));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 8));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 0));
#else
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 0));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 8));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 16));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 24));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 32));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 40));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 48));
    m_vBuffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(ruiValue >> 56));
#endif

}



uint64_t CSerializer::Read_uint64()
{
    uint64_t uiret;

#if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
    uiret = ((static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 0]) << 56) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 1]) << 48) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 2]) << 40) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 3]) << 32) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 4]) << 24) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 5]) << 16) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 6]) << 8) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 7]) << 0));
#else
    uiret = ((static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 0]) << 0) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 1]) << 8) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 2]) << 16) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 3]) << 24) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 4]) << 32) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 5]) << 40) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 6]) << 48) |
             (static_cast<uint64_t>( m_vBuffer[m_iOffset + 7]) << 56));
#endif

    m_iOffset += sizeof(uint64_t);
    return uiret;
}
```

Then i test the results with a simple check:

```
CSerializer _Ser;
    _Ser.Write_uint64(1234567890123456789);


    uint64_t uiResults = _Ser.Read_uint64();
    printf("- %li\n", uiResults);



    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("dump.dat","wb");
    for(int a = 0; a < _Ser.GetBuffer().size(); a++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%c", _Ser.GetBuffer()[a]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

But the results are not equal on two platforms (Mac OSX / Raspberry), here are the results:

```
MacBook:SerializerTest cdr$ uname -a
Darwin MacBook.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
MacBook:SerializerTest pawel$ ./SerializerTest 
- 1234567890123456789
MacBook:SerializerTest pawel$ hexdump dump.dat 
0000000 15 81 e9 7d f4 10 22 11                        
0000008
MacBook:SerializerTest cdr$ 





root@raspberrypi:/G/SerializerTest# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
root@raspberrypi:/G/SerializerTest# ./SerializerTest 
- 287445236
root@raspberrypi:/G/SerializerTest# hexdump dump.dat 
0000000 8115 7de9 10f4 1122                    
0000008
root@raspberrypi:/G/SerializerTest#
```

I can see that values (in hex) are swapped, i can't figure out what's wrong...

Comment: I don't think the bytes are swapped -- it is just that hexdump is displaying 16 bit ints. Try 'hexdump -C' on the raspberry pi. Also, "%li" appears to be only printing a 32-bit value on raspberry pi, you might try "%lli".

Comment: Yes you're right 'hexdump -C' shows the same output on both machines now.

Comment: And yes, you're right with the %lli on PI. It works OK when printed with %lli instead of %li.

Gosh..

Comment: It works now? I guess I should make my comment an answer then ...

Comment: @MarkkuK. Thanks for that, you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes are not swapped, it is just that `hexdump` displays 2-byte ints by default on some platforms. You should be able to use `hexdump -C` to get 1-byte ints. Also, on 32-bit architectures such as the raspberry pi, the printf format "%li" (long int) is also for 32-bit ints. You need "%lli" to correctly show a 64-bit int.

Comment: Perfect, all clear and it worked as a charm.
Much appreciated!